# How to have a global help box with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an `AppController` in my `body` tag that is acting as a global controller. I also have a `div` anchored to the bottom to show updating help.

When you mouseover a field, I want to take the `data-hint` attribute and display it in the `help-div`. How can I do this with AngularJS?

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngMouseover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your controller:**

```
app.controller('AppController', function($scope){
    ...
    $scope.defaultHelpText = 'look here for help';
    $scope.helpText = $scope.defaultHelpText;
    ...
    $scope.helpElem1 = {text: 'this is important'};
    $scope.helpElem2 = {text: 'this is also important'};
    ....
});
```

**Your "help" `<div>` at the bottom:**

```
<div class="help-text"> {{helpText}} </div>
```

**Any elements that trigger the text to update:**

```
<div class="hover-over-me" ng-mouseenter="helpText = helpElem1.text" ng-mouseleave="helpText = defaultHelpText">
    {{helpElem1.text}}
</div>

<div class="hover-over-me" ng-mouseenter="helpText = helpElem2.text" ng-mouseleave="helpText = defaultHelpText">
    {{helpElem2.text}}
</div>
```

Hopefully that helps you get pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I want to have the help text embedded in the `div`, like `<div class="help-text" data-hint="whatever">`. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: If you really want to be able to pull the data out of an attribute on the element, you'd have to write your own custom `hint` directive.  can you not just embed the text into the `ng-mouseenter` attribute instead of the `data-hint` attribute?